# Unable to fetch data from server : JSON Parsing Error

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-studio

I want to Parse JSON data from server:

I created activity_main.xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"    android:background="#F1F1F1"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row" >

</ListView>
```

and created listview-row.xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="4dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ചെമ്മീന്‍ തീയല്‍"
            android:textColor="#166CED"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="Non-Veg" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPreparation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#009A57"
    android:text="sdfdfds " />
```

after that I created Actors class like this:

```
    public class Actors {

    private String name;
    private String preparation;
    private String category;
    private String photo;

    public Actors() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Actors(String name, String preparation, String category, String photo) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.preparation = preparation;
        this.category = category;
        this.photo = photo;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPreparation() {
        return preparation;
    }

    public void setPreparation(String preparation) {
        this.preparation = preparation;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
```

then I created Actors Adapter like this:

```
 public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {
    ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        actorList = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.tvPreparation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPreparation);
            holder.tvCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getPhoto());
        holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvPreparation.setText(actorList.get(position).getPreparation());
        holder.tvCategory.setText(actorList.get(position).getCategory());

        return v;

}

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvPreparation;
        public TextView tvCategory;

    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }
}
```

I called the adapter in MainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;

ActorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();


    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://localhost:8000/api/recepie");

    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
        }
    });
}


class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("recepies");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    actor.setPreparation(object.getString("preparation"));
                    actor.setCategory(object.getString("category"));
                    actor.setPhoto(object.getString("photo"));

                    actorsList.add(actor);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

But get **"Unable to fetch data from server"**,and i find the two error in Android Monitor..first one is **Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache** ,and  **Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()**. Any wrong with my JSON parsing?
 What should I do to correct that code ?

Comment: Can you show your logcat with error ?

Comment: Try to check if you are actually getting any response from server. Using Log print the data string and check logcat

Comment: check whether the response is the valid json.

Comment: You are getting data asynchronously, and adding it to `actorsList`. But as soon as you requesting data you using `actorList` which is I guess empty.

Comment: You should check 2 things : First, do the address that you wanna get data from work. Second, did your application could access internet (check internet availability, check `INTERNET_PERMISSION`)